# hadoop permission denied while copying data from local to remote hdfs location in scala using file system

Tags: scala, hadoop, permissions, hdfs, acl

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=practice, access=WRITE, inode="/user/rnd/data":rnd:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkFsPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:271)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:257)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:6512)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:6494)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkAncestorAccess(FSNamesystem.java:6446)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2712)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInt(FSNamesystem.java:2632)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFile(FSNamesystem.java:2519)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.create(NameNodeRpcServer.java:566)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.create(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:962)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2039)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2035)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2033)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.newStreamForCreate(DFSOutputStream.java:1653)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.create(DFSClient.java:1689)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.create(DFSClient.java:1624)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$7.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:448)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$7.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.create(DistributedFileSystem.java:459)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.create(DistributedFileSystem.java:387)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:892)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:789)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:778)
    at com.dataflair.spark.Hdfs$.main(Translation.scala:25)
    at com.dataflair.spark.Hdfs.main(Translation.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): Permission denied: user=practice, access=WRITE, inode="/user/rnd/data":rnd:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkFsPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:271)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:257)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:6512)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:6494)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkAncestorAccess(FSNamesystem.java:6446)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2712)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInt(FSNamesystem.java:2632)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFile(FSNamesystem.java:2519)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.create(NameNodeRpcServer.java:566)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.create(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:962)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2039)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2035)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2033)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1475)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.create(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.create(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:296)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.create(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.newStreamForCreate(DFSOutputStream.java:1648)
    ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Weel, your user `practice` needs to get permissions in that folder

```
/user/rnd/data
```

If you are the admin you should run the setACL command both for your user and for the group's default

```
hdfs dfs -setfacl -R -m user:practice:rwx /user/rnd/data
hdfs dfs -setfacl -R -m default:user:groupName:rwx /user/rnd/data
```

More info can be found [here](https://hortonworks.com/blog/hdfs-acls-fine-grained-permissions-hdfs-files-hadoop/) and [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html#ACLs_File_System_API)

Comment: Thank you, can I change permissions through java filesystem operation?

Comment: Never did, but it seems that it's possible through this API:

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html#ACLs_File_System_API